# Need Help with Older Version of EE

Tags: ee2

I have a client that has an old version of EE running on their site (v 2.1.3) and we just migrated their site to a new server with MySQL 5.7.  This broke several pages of their site, and we are aware of the issue. We are not the developers of the site, and the original developers are MIA.

Problem is, client wants us to fix this as quickly as and inexpensively as possible, and it looks like the MySQL bug was fixed in 2.11.0, but I see no way to get ahold of that build since it's very old, no longer supported.  Willing to pay for it, but just don' know how to download it.

Upgrading to 3 or higher will be problematic with add ons, so we just need to correct this issue asap.

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Tom

Answer (score 2):

If you upgrade your EE2 license to EE3 you'll get access to the final version of EE2 (you need this, as you cannot upgrade directly from anything less than EE2.10 if I remember rightly).  It will appear alongside your EE3 download.

HTH

Comment: This is the answer. Upgrade their site license and you will get access to download EE 2.11.9 for  that license.